# Add "Photo"form to my form to allow users to add a photo

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I'd like to add Imageform to my form to allow all users to add a photo. 
I've read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#imagefield
and this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files

but still I'm confused about how to achieve that. How can I change my codes to allow users to add a photo from their own folders?Here's my codes and I also attached the ideal form I'd like to create.

[My ideal form]

[image: My Ideal Form]

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Sell(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from uasite1.models import Sell

class SellForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sell
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from uasite1.forms import SellForm
from uasite1.models import Sell
from django.template import RequestContext

def sell_create(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SellForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():            
            new_sell = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/sechand/%d/' % new_sell.pk)
    else:
        form = SellForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('sell.html',context,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

sell.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block extrahead %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "/sechand/" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

<input type = "submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% endblock%}
```

sell_display.html  (this is the template where the submitted information would show up.)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div id = 'sell'>

    <h3> Product Name : [ {{ sell.subject }}]</h3>
    <p>Photo{{ sell.photo }}</p>
    <p>Price: [ {{ sell.price }} ]</p>
    <p>Condition: [ {{ sell.condition }} ]</p>
    <p>Comments: [ {{sell.body}} ]</p>
    <p>Contact Email:[ {{ sell.email }} ]</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^sechand/$','uasite1.views.sell_create'),
    url(r'^sechand/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'uasite1.views.sell_detail'),
    url(r'^products/electronics/$', 'uasite1.views.Electronics'),
    url(r'^products/$', 'uasite1.views.ProductsAll'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not go through your entire code but I can notice 1 important mistake, view should have the following:

```
form = SellForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Also, this line:

```
<p>Photo{{ sell.photo }}</p>
```

I don't think that's the way to show a photo, I would put a link to the photo doing:

```
<p>Photo{{ sell.photo.url }}</p>
```

And finally, for development environments you may want to serve media files so just add this line to your main urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# your url patterns in here
```

) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

editing:

[Serving media files](http://www.muhuk.com/2009/05/25/serving-static-media-in-django-development-server.html#.UJsxE7TA-0w). That link should give you a good overview, it's confusing I know, so I am going to give you an example, just like I do in my projects. First the way I do it in settings.py:

```
#settings.py
from os.path import dirname, join, realpath
# have in mind that I have settings.py under project_root/project/settings.py
# so you probably want to check your path to your project root folder first
ROOT_DIR = realpath(join(dirname(__file__), '..'))
MEDIA_ROOT = realpath(join(ROOT_DIR, 'media'))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    join(ROOT_DIR, "static"),
)
```

That's the way I do it, you could find many ways that also work. To give you a better clue my folders look like this:

```
project_root/
    media/
    static/
    project/
        settings.py
```

Comment: Thank you, but how should I set the "MEDIA_URL" ?